# JavaScript using the same variable in 2 different if statements

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to create a squad system for DiscordJS but I can not access the same variable inside a different if statement. As I know, there is no block scope in JavaScript so I wanted to ask here.

```
squads = []
nextSquad = 0
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("createsquad")) {
    squadMessage = message.content.split(" ")
    squadMessage = squadMessage.slice(1)
    squadMessage = squadMessage.join(" ")
    squadMessage = squadMessage.split(" , ")
    if (!typeof squadMessage[0] === "string" || !typeof squadMessage[1] === "number") return

    squads[nextSquad] = {squadName: squadMessage[0], squadSlot: squadMessage[1], squadAuthor: message.author.username}

    nextSquad = nextSquad + 1
    console.log(squads[0])
    // Result : { squadName: 'IDK', squadSlot: '4', squadAuthor: 'Scaevian' }
}

if (message.content.toLowerCase() === "listsquads"){
    console.log(squads[0])
    //Result : undefined
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that when `message.content.toLowerCase() === "listsquads"`, `squads` is an empty array?

Comment: Thats the point I am trying to use the same array in two different if statement

Comment: It should work. Are you sure there is undefined? What will happen if you write "let squads = []" instead of squads = []

Comment: It didn't change the result, still undefined.

Comment: I also checked out the array itself and it is not changing when I use the command more than 1 time, I tried to use .push() but still the same

Comment: I just realized that I declared variable inside the block which gets triggered everyime it gets a message. This is causing array to reset everytime I send a message. That solved the problem.